# How to call a method in full life time of the application

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-syncadapter, android-backup-service

i am developing sample application, it has a sqlite and mysql databases. if internet connection has data goes to the web server database(mysql database), if haven' t a internet connection data save sqlite database, after reopening application synchronizing with the web server database(mysql database), now i want to synchronizing web server database(mysql database) with out reopening the application, run time of the application should be synchronizing. help me

Comment: i think static block is helpful for you

Comment: tell me another way..

Answer (score 1):

Use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and declare it in the `AndroidManifest` with...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
```

You wil also need...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

...in the manifest.

In the `onReceive(...)` method of the `BroadcastReceiver` check the `Intent` to see what change has occurred - if it has changed to connected, you can start a sync operation.

To perform the sync, use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which will perform the work on a worker thread and then self-terminate when the work is done.

If you want periodic backups, you should also consider using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to create a repeating alarm which can be used to fire the `IntentService` at regular intervals. In this case the `IntentService` will obviously have to perform an explicit check to see if there is a connection to the Internet available.